# Autocorrelation and Autoconvolution

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, laplace-transform

Let $f(t)$ be a stochastic process. Suppose that I know $F(s)$, which is also a stochastic process and is the Laplace transform of $f(t)$. I also know the values $\langle F(s) \rangle$ and $\langle F^2(s)\rangle$, and I can compute the mean auto-convolution of $f(t)$ based on the relationship
\begin{equation}
\left\langle f(t) * f(t)\right\rangle = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\left\langle F^2(s)\right\rangle \right].
\end{equation}
My question is, if I am interested in an expression like $\langle f^2(t) \rangle$, or $\langle f(t) f(t+\tau)\rangle$ (auto-correlation), is there any way to extract this information from the auto-convolution of $f(t)$? Is there any mathematical theorem that connects the auto-convolution and auto-correlation of a stochastic process, just like there is one for time-continuous deterministic signals?

Side note: we define the variance of a stochastic process as
\begin{equation}
\text{Var}[f(t)] = \left\langle f^2(t)\right\rangle - \left\langle f(t)\right\rangle^2,
\end{equation}
so is there an analogous expression for something like
\begin{equation}
\left\langle f(t) * f(t)\right\rangle - \left\langle f(t)\right\rangle * \left\langle f(t)\right\rangle = ?
\end{equation}